# How to know where some file is loaded with Chrome Development Tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I am getting an error loading some file in JS console. How to know, where loading is called from?

Right hand side message refers to the file and line where is no load instruction located.

Here it is. `service.htm`, line 1, does not contain code to load from `front.facetz.net`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can see it in the Network-tab
[image]